# Flex TextFlowUtil.importFromString ignoring whitespace in some cases. Is this a bug?

Tags: apache-flex

In the following complete functional Flex application the line breaks between the two links ought to be preserved when importing the input text into the TextFlow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application         xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.formats.WhiteSpaceCollapse;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import spark.utils.TextFlowUtil;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event : FlexEvent) : void
            {
                input.text = "<a href='#'>link1</a>\n<a href='#'>link2</a>";
            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event : MouseEvent) : void
            {
                output.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(input.text, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:RichEditableText text=""
                        id="input"
                        width="266" height="215"
                        x="10" y="30"
                        />
    <s:Label text="Input"
             x="10" y="10"
             />
    <s:Label text="Output"
             x="8" y="286"
             />
    <s:Button x="10" y="253"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)"
              label="Import"
              />
    <s:RichEditableText id="output"
                        width="399" height="212"
                        x="10" y="306"
                        />
</s:Application>
```

But if you click "Import" you will see the two links created in the same line (no break).

This changes if you add any non-whitespace character between the links in the source text. Meaning, if you just add a "*" between the links the line breaks will be preserved.

What gives? Is this a Flex bug?

Comment: if you think it's a bug, please vote on it in Adobe's bug system: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29566

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust the global XML parsing settings.  These are accessible as static properties of the `XML` class.  My hunch is that `XML.ignoreWhitespace` is `true` at the time of parsing.  Try the following:

```
XML.ignoreWhitespace = false;
output.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(input.text, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE);
```

Comment: It's not being imported from XML, though. It's a text field that the user populates. It also wouldn't explain why line breaks _are_ preserved, just not between the links.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to solve this bug, and there is no need for changing any XML settings, simple and it works:

Exporting the `TextFlow`:

```
var richTextXML:xml = new XML("<"+"richTextXML"+"/>");    
richTextXML.appendChild(getCdataXMl());

private function getCdataXMl():xml {
    var textFlowStr:String = TextConverter.export(textFlow,TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT, ConversionType.STRING_TYPE).toString();
    var textFlowXMl:xml = new XMl("<![CDATA["+textFlowStr+"]]>");
    return textFlowXMl;
}
```

Importing `TextFlow` from XML:

```
var htmlTextInStr:String = richTextXMl.text();
var importtedTextFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlTextInStr,TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
textArea.textFlow = importtedTextFlow;
```